# Proguard keep all inner classes that implement some interface

Tags: java, android, proguard

What is wrong with the following definition?

-keep class com.foo.bar.** implements android.content.ServiceConnection {
  *;
}

I need to keep the onServiceConnected or disconnected methods in:

com.foo.bar.SomeClass$SomeInnerClass$SomeInnerInnerClass implements ServiceConnection {
 // Methods that I need to keep
}

Proguard always strips them out.

The only solution I found so far is too keep the whole com.foo.bar package.

Note: I cannot keep com.foo.bar.SomeClass because the name can change. I am given a JAR file that contains already pro-guarded code. So SomeClass is actually called "dw" and and SomeInnerClass is actually called "a". But I cannot rely on that obviously.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks correct, but ProGuard already automatically keeps methods that implement methods in runtime interfaces like ServiceConnection. You don't need to specify them explicitly. You can look at bin/proguard/mapping.txt to see the old/new names of the classes and the methods. You can use the Android tool `dexdump` to inspect the classes.dex file, to double-check that the classes are present, that they implement the interface, and that the methods are present.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special situation for me. I proguard a single jar file and just keep a custom not system interface implementation and obfuscate others including method content. I try a lot, and find a way satisfies me more or less.

```
-keepclassmembernames class aa.bb.Impl {
    public <methods>;
}
```